# PyGtk - Can't open the same window twice

Tags: pygtk

I've been using PyGtk to make an indicator that will show a preferences window when a button is pressed. The window is built once and opened using show_all() on a button press. When opened a second time, however, there widgets in the window disappear. Is there a way I can show and close the same window multiple times? The following code will reproduce the problem after closing it for the first time

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import gtk

def show():
    window.show_all()
    return True

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
gtk.timeout_add(2000, show)
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the window instead of closing it.

Adding the following code will hide the window when the close button is clicked.

```
def hide_window(window, event):
    window.hide()
    return True

window.connect('delete-event', hide_window)
```

From the PyGTK FAQ:
http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq10.021.htp